# How to get all the classes of an application specified with identifier in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak, objective-c-runtime, tweak

I want to get all the classes of a specified application (maybe any other apps, not only the app itself) at runtime, I can get the `NSBundle` of that application with it's identifier, but how can I get the classes with the `NSBundle`, or can I get the classes directly with the application's identifier? We assume it could be a jailbroken environment.I tryied `objc_copyClassNamesForImage` but failed, does any one have ideas?

```
NSBundle * bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:appIdentifier];
NSString * bundlePath = [bundle bundlePath];
NSLog(@"%@", bundlePath);

unsigned int count;
const char **classes;

classes = objc_copyClassNamesForImage([bundlePath UTF8String], &count);

for (int i = 0; i< sizeof(classes)/sizeof(classes[0]); i++){
    NSLog(@"class name: %s", classes[i]);
}
```

Comment: Grab the source code to class-dump and go for it.

Comment: `objc_copyClassNamesForImage` only works if the bundle is loaded, sadly (though this is not a documented fact, you can see it in objc-runtime.mm:536). Did you attempt to load the bundle using `-[bundle load]`, and then using `objc_copyClassNamesForImage` on the bundles `executablePath` instead of `bundlePath`?

Comment: The other solution, is similar to what @bbum mentioned, is to disassemble the mach-o binary of the target executable, and read the class headers from there (the format isn't too complicated, especially if you just want names. You can look at `_getObjc2ClassList` and its usages inside `objc-runtime-new.mm`).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, I haven't tried to load the bundle before using `objc_copyClassNamesForImage `, I'll try it now, but is it(load bundle before objc_copyClassNamesForImage) a resource intensive process?Do we have any graceful way to get all the classes of an application with it's identifier?

Comment: @Suge no, you're delving well into the realm of unsupported use cases here. FYI, the relevant `DATA` section that holds all the objective-c class references before they're loaded by the runtime is `__objc_classlist`, (which you may be able to use with the mach-o APIs in `<mach-o/getsect.h>`).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, but I want to get all the classes just at runtime to check if the applications have a class inherit from a specified class, so is `class-dump` unapplicable?

Comment: @Suge I've never looked at the implementation of class-dump, TBH. I'm not sure how easy it would be to find that information vs. just parsing the class list yourself. Either way, there's no simple solution to this problem. Maybe take a step back and think about what you're really trying to accomplish, and go from there.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, I have just looked up the informations about  `__objc_classlist `, `<mach-o/getsect.h>`, and `class-dump`'s source code, it looks like that is a heavy way to achieve my purpose, so I should look for other ways, thank you all the same.